Remove model created with choices and the choices too
Sometime ago I created a model with some choices:
class MyEnum(StrEnum):
    CREATE = "create"
    DELETE = "delete"

class ShareHistory(models.Model):
    action = models.TextField(choices=MyEnum.get_choices())
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_created=True)

After some time I understood that I don't need that model. So I can just remove the class, run makemigrations, then run migrate and that is all, the table is gone.
But I want to remove the choices too (MyEnum). If I do that the next time someone runs the migrations from scratch will receive an error, because the initial migration needs MyEnum. Is there a way to remove that?
Part of the migrations file:
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('contenttypes', '0002_remove_content_type_name'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='ShareHistory',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('created_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_created=True, auto_now_add=True)),
                ('action', models.TextField(choices=[
                    (MyEnum['CREATE'],
                     MyEnum['CREATE']),
                    (MyEnum['DELETE'],
                     MyEnum['DELETE']),
                ])),
            ],
        ),
    ]


https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/migrations/#historical-models TLDR squash migrations

if initial migrations needs MyEnum(proabably to create some other model(if I am getting it correct)), why do you want to remove it in the first place ?

@shivankgtm the MyEnum was needed for the model I want to delete. After I deleting the model is not necessary. But in the migration that Django created you will have the MyEnum.

@pepe_botika69, can you paste the migration file that is causing issue. I want to understand how this MyEnum is being used in migrations.

@shivankgtm Done. Do you see choices? there is the problem

@iklinac it did not help me. I got CreateModel and the DeleteModel

If I could understand you correctly you don't want to work with the model you stated above again, but the my_enum class refused to get deleted from your program? Please can you show us the error traceback from your terminal?

you can manually edit squashed migration to remove useless operations

@iklinac well it looks like is the only way to fix it. Thanks

@Blaisemart Well, there is no error. The problem is that i cant remove MyEnum class, because it is used in the migration.
